# Modifying the section, subsection and subsubsection style

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning

I want to create this style:

[image]

I want this executed every time I use the command for the `section`, `subsection` and the `sub​​subsection`

I already have the code for the graphics, but I do not know how to do all this is done automatically when each command is written, or how to make the format does not move.

anyone can help me to do this??

```
\documentclass[oneside,spanish,10pt, letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{3cm}{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,americanresistors]{circuitikz}
\definecolor{logo}{HTML}{6C17A1}
\definecolor{logo2}{HTML}{FFFF10}
\usepackage{color} 
\def\sectionfont{\sffamily\LARGE}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%%%Section
\fill[logo](4,-1) rectangle (0,-2);
\draw[color = logo2] (0.5,-1.7) to[R,o-o,label=\mbox{$R_1=\SI{1.1}{\ohm}$}] (2.5,-1.7);
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=white,scale=1,font=\sectionfont]  at (3.2,-1.5)    {1.1};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=logo,scale=1,font=\sectionfont]  at (5.5,-1.5)   {Some text};

%%%sub section
\fill[logo](1.2,-3) rectangle (1.7,-4);
\fill[logo](1.2,-3.95) rectangle (14,-4);
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=logo,scale=1,font=\sectionfont]  at (.5,-3.5)  {1.1.1};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=logo,scale=1.2,font=\sffamily]  at (2.8,-3.5){Some text};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=logo2,scale=1,font=\sectionfont]  at (1.45,-3.5){$\oint$};
\draw[color = logo] (13.99,-4) node [ground] {};

%%%subsub section
\fill[logo](1.7,-5) rectangle (2.2,-6);
\fill[logo](1.7,-5.95) rectangle (12,-6);
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=logo,scale=1,font=\sectionfont]  at (.9,-5.5){1.1.1.1};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=logo,scale=1.2,font=\itshape]  at (3.5,-5.5){Some text};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=logo2,scale=1,font=\sectionfont]  at (1.95,-5.5){$\psi$};
\draw[color = logo] (11.99,-6) node [ground] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I imagine you could accomplish this with the help of the sectsty package

Comment: Or perhaps with `titlesec`.

Comment: Not to kill the mood of this fun question but I think it is not readable as a section decoration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution using native commands of `memoir`:

```
\documentclass[oneside,spanish,10pt, letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{3cm}{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,americanresistors]{circuitikz}
\definecolor{logo}{HTML}{6C17A1}
\definecolor{logo2}{HTML}{FFFF10}
\usepackage{color} 
\def\sectionfont{\sffamily\LARGE}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}% to number subsubsections

% SECTIONS
\makeatletter
\setsecheadstyle{\tikz{\fill[logo](4,-1) rectangle (0,-2);
\draw[color = logo2] (0.5,-1.7) to[R,o-o,label=\mbox{$R_1=\SI{1.1}{\ohm}$}] (2.5,-1.7);
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=white,scale=1,font=\sectionfont]  at (3.2,-1.5)    {\thesection};}\vskip-6ex\sectionfont\color{logo}}

\def\@seccntformat#1{\hskip10em}
\makeatother

\setbeforesecskip{-1\onelineskip}
\setaftersecskip{2\onelineskip}

% SUBSECTIONS
\setsubsecheadstyle{\tikz{\fill[logo](1.2,-3) rectangle (1.7,-4);
\fill[logo](1.2,-3.95) rectangle (14,-4);
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=logo,scale=1,font=\sectionfont]  at (.5,-3.5)  {\thesubsection};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=logo2,scale=1,font=\sectionfont]  at (1.45,-3.5){$\oint$};
\draw[color = logo] (13.99,-4) node [ground] {};}\vskip-9ex\hskip-4em\sffamily\color{logo}
}

\setbeforesubsecskip{-1\onelineskip}
\setaftersubsecskip{3\onelineskip}

% SUBSUBSECTIONS
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\tikz{\fill[logo](1.7,-5) rectangle (2.2,-6);
\fill[logo](1.7,-5.95) rectangle (12,-6);
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=logo,scale=1,font=\sectionfont]  at (.9,-5.5){\thesubsubsection};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=logo2,scale=1,font=\sectionfont]  at (1.95,-5.5){$\psi$};
\draw[color = logo] (11.99,-6) node [ground] {};}\vskip-9ex\hskip-3em\sffamily\color{logo}
}

\setbeforesubsubsecskip{-1\onelineskip}
\setaftersubsubsecskip{3\onelineskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter title}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Some text}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Some text}
\lipsum[3-5]
\subsubsection{Some text}
\lipsum[6]

\chapter{Another chapter title}
\section{Some text}
\subsection{Some text}
\subsubsection{Some text}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]